# An open source video streaming application that uses RTP over UDP that I can 'make' from the source code?

Tags: video, networking, video-conferencing

I am looking for an application that allows me to modify its source code according to my custom needs. I have a packet with custom information with a separate software to process and do stuff with it. I need a video streaming application to test my protocol. I will need to modify the application's source code say, to send the packet out the particular port, set the bandwidth, and so on. Is there any application? I couldn't find any. I tried looking for one on github and sourceforge.